# Azure CloudBlockBlob.downloadText() operation failing with Blob hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is xxxx, retrieved xxx

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Azure Storage Java SDK CloudBlockBlob.downloadText() operation failing with error: "Blob hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is xxxx, retrieved xxx".

I'm using azure storage sdk version: azure-storage:8.0.0. Here is the code snippet.

```
List<BlockEntry> blockList = new ArrayList<BlockEntry>();

File parent = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

File temp = new File(parent, "sample-file.txt");
String blockText="hellow world";

    if (temp.exists()) {
        temp.delete();
    }

    try {
        temp.createNewFile();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(temp.getName());
        blob.uploadFromFile(temp.getAbsolutePath());

        //Add Block to the created blob
        String blockId1 = Base64.encode("B1".getBytes());
        InputStream inputStream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(blockText.getBytes());

        long len = -1;

        BlockEntry block1 = new BlockEntry(blockId1);

        blockList.add(block1);

        blockBlob.uploadBlock(blockId1, inputStream1, len);
        blockBlob.commitBlockList(blockList);

        //Print the blob content
        System.out.println("Printing the block content" + blob.downloadText());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit, which version of the SDK you are using ? Could you share some code also ?

Comment: I have added the sdk version and code snippet above. Kindly let me know for anymore details. Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with the blocklist ? Dont really understand what youre doing

Comment: I’m working in blob APIs, I have created an empty blob and added a block of text to it using blockList. Now my requirement is to download the block content and compare it with a static text to see, if the text is same or not. If the content is same, will return true  else will return false.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, kindly let me know, if get a chance to find the root cause of the issue or is there is any limitation in Java SDK?. Thanks